# Inflating preferences dynamically in PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library, preferencefragment

I'm using the PreferenceFragmentCompat from the support library (preference-v14:23.0.1 - although I've also tried it with 23.1.1). I have all my preference settings in an XML file and inflate them in onCreatePreferences as normal:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreatePreferences(final Bundle bundle, final String s) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_settings);
```

When the fragment is first shown I want to hide some of the preferences until I get the results of a network call back where I may want to show those preferences again.

I tried setting the visibility on various preferences to false in the hope that I would then be able to set them visible again later but it looks like :

```
Preference preference = findPreference(getString(R.string.settings_key_value));
preference.setVisible(false);
```

Effectively removes the preference from the list and when I try the find on the Preference again later it returns null.

As an alternative, I then created a method to create preference that I could then add to the relevant screen/position in the adapter:

```
private Preference createPreference(@StringRes int title, @StringRes int key, @StringRes int summary, int order) {
    final Preference preference = new Preference(getContext());
    preference.setTitle(title);
    preference.setKey(getString(key));
    if (summary > 0) {
        preference.setSummary(summary);
    }
    preference.setOrder(order);
    return preference;
}
```

I then use it as follows:

```
final PreferenceCategory category = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference(getString(R.string.settings_category_name));
preference = createPreference(R.string.pref_title, R.string.settings_pref_key, R.string.pref_summary, 0);
category.addPreference(preference);
```

However, when I do this the font size of the preference title is incorrect (and possibly other stylings within the Preference). This is presumably because the attribute set of the preference is not set and it's not inheriting the preference style from my app theme. Is there a way to either inflate an individual preference correctly from xml so that it has the correct styling and add it to my preferences list or to modify the createPreference method so that it will use the correct styling?

My AppTheme is defined with the following pertinent attribute:

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
```

Comment: For the moment I've fixed this by replacing the SettingsFragment with a new one when I get new information from the network - but obviously this isn't ideal - it doesn't make advantage of the Preference list being in a recyclerview and animating the new preferences appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Use themed context created by addPreferencesFromResource for you dynamic properties. Get and keep it the following way:

```
Context styledContext;

@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    styledContext=getPreferenceScreen().getContext();
    ....
}
```

In case you hide (removes) some properties and need to back them from XML use th following code line:

```
   setPreferenceScreen(
        getPreferenceManager().inflateFromResource(
                  styledContext,
                  R.xml.preferences,
                  null)
        );
```

Comment: How would this be better than just recreating the fragment again from scratch? I still don't get the nice RecyclerView animations to show that Items have been added or removed?

Comment: At first you are asked about wrong styling. I point you the case how to create dynamic items with correct style.

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep a reference to the `Preference` in a field and `setVisible(true)` later.

`setVisible(false)` removes the `Preference` from the hierarchy but `setVisible(true)` will re-add it to the hierarchy.

Comment: This works for one or two preferences but if I update the visibility of 4 or 5 then I get the following errors:  Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 13, size is 13 in android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.onPreferenceVisibilityChange(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:241